# CometD connection on ios7

Tags: xcode, ios7, connection, cometd

I was asked to establish a connection using the cometD library going from ios7 to a server. After some research I came to the conclusion that my two options were Dave Duncan's DDComet, and Paul Crawford's FayeObjC. I tried using DDComet, but when I opened the github project, it came with 30+ errors. They were mainly ARC errors witch I attempted to fix, but it only ended up crashing the application. I then took a look at the FayeObjC documentation, and quickly realized that it had very little/nothing to do with cometD.
My question is: Is CometD an outdated library? If so, what should I be using as a replacement. If not, how would I be able to implement it in ios7?

Answer (score 1):

CometD is not an outdated library. The last version of CometD is barely one month old.
The CometD project does not have an ObjC client.

I know of companies that have written one and maintain themselves that is fully compatible with CometD 2.x and 3.x.
It may happen that in future their implementation is open sourced.

Faye uses the Bayeux protocol, defined by the CometD project, so in *theory* they should be able to interoperate. However, I don't know exactly the status of either Faye or FayeObjC.

As the CometD project leader I'd love to have an ObjC client in the project, but it has not happened yet.